# In spatial description, why should Eulerian coordinates keep changing in material derivative?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, coordinate-systems, continuum-mechanics

I feel confused about spatial description, the text *An introduction to continuum mechanics* by J N Reddy says,

> *"For a fixed value of $\mathbf{x}\in\kappa$ (the current configuration), $\phi(\mathbf{x},t)$ gives the value of $\phi$ associated with a fixed point x in space, which will be the value of $\phi$ associated with different material points at different times,..."*.

So we should keep $\mathbf{x}$ unchanged, right? Because it says "fixed point". But material derivative is expressed by
$$\frac{D}{Dt}[\phi(\mathbf{x},t)]=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}[\phi(\mathbf{x},t)]+\sum_i\underbrace{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}[\phi(\mathbf{x},t)]}_{\text{why?}}\frac{dx_i}{dt}
=\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}+\mathbf{v}\cdot\nabla\phi,$$
where $\mathbf{x}$ is Eulerian coordinates and $\mathbf{v}=d\mathbf{x}/dt$. I do know chain rule but according to the statement in the book, if $\mathbf{x}$ holds constant, there is no partial derivative $ \partial\phi/\partial x_i$, right? Hope someone can interpret it, thanks so much.

Note that material coordinates ($\boldsymbol{\xi}$) and spatial coordinates ($\mathbf{x}$) have the relation
$$\mathbf{x}=\chi(\boldsymbol{\xi},t),\boldsymbol{\xi}=\chi^{-1}(\mathbf{x},t)$$
where $\chi$ is the mapping.

Comment: As an aside, the double negative in the title can be confusing for some readers (see [this Thesaurus.com article](https://www.thesaurus.com/e/grammar/double-negatives/) for instance).

Comment: @KyleKanos Thanks for your reminder. I changed the title; it may be better now.

Answer (score 0):

Representing $\phi$ as $\phi=\phi(x,t)$ means that it is varying with spatial position.  The material time derivative is the rate of change of $\phi$ as reckoned by an observer who is moving with a material fluid parcel as the fluid flows.  It is the derivative with respect to time at constant $\xi$.  We have $$d\phi=\left(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}\right)_tdx+\left(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}\right)_xdt$$and so $$\left(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}\right)_{\xi}=\frac{D\phi}{Dt}=\left(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}\right)_tv+\left(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}\right)_x$$where $$v=\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}\right)_{\xi}$$

Comment: Hello, since $\mathbf{x}$ can be differentiated with respect to $t$ ($\partial x_i/\partial t$), we can know that the relation $\mathbf{x}=\chi(\boldsymbol{\xi},t)$ is used. So velocity is $\partial x_i(\xi,t)/\partial t$, which is Material description. This is confusing because spatial and material description mix together. What is its meaning?

Comment: You are holding the material parcel constant, and measuring the changes in its spatial coordinates with time.  This is the same as. you being in a car, and noting the km markers along the roadside as a function of time.